# How to be sure that my scale axis does not vary from a graph to the other with the same set palette defined?

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting maps of interactions between residues of differents proteins. The maps should have the same z scale. x,y are the residue number of the proteins, z is the pourcentage of interaction. I used 
set palette defined (0.0 "white", 1. "green")
And I expected that for each data the map would be plot with a scale ranging from 0 to 1. However the range adapts systematically to the maximum and minimum, and for example instead of having a color range from 0 to 1, everything is rescaled from 0 to 0.25 because no values superior at 0.25 are present in the specific data.
Hence my maps are not similar and cannot be compared.

I have only found that autoscale is automatically applied. However, when I
unset autoscale
The map is all green.
Below is my gnuplot script.

reset
set title "G2-5 Fondaparinux Hbonds Hbonds"
set palette defined (0.0 "white", 1. "green")
set xtics 5 border mirror
set ytics 5 border mirror
set xrange [0:49]
set yrange [47.5:63]
set nokey
set terminal svg size 1024,748
set xlabel "DGL residue number"
set ylabel "Heparin residue number"
set output 'G5_F_Hbonds_Hbonds.svg'
plot 'G5F.txt' u 1:2:(1.0):6 w p pt 5 ps var lc palette z

Corresponding graph :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pin the two ends of the defined color palette to predetermined values, use
`set cbrange [min:max]`.  In this case

```
  set cbrange [0:1]
```